# How to use Socket.ReceiveAsync with Memory<byte>?

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-core

I was going to play around with System.IO.Pipelines, but am failing early. In the example at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/07/09/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/#tcp-server-with-systemiopipelines, they're using on overload of Socket.ReadAsync that works on a `Memory<byte>`.

I cannot for the life of me find such an overload. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you installed the System.IO.Pipelines NuGet package?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I guess it should rather be in System.Memory because that part doesn't have to do with pipelines yet (changed question title accordingly)

Comment: Found something here but it's an internal method: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.Tasks.cs

Comment: I don't see them using Socket.ReadAsync() in the blog post, only  [NetworkStream.ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It's in line 20 in the code labeled "TCP server with System.IO.Pipelines"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To (once again, sorry) answer my own question: I had to update to .NET Core 2.1 to get this working.

And yes, it's there right at the top of the blog post: "progressed into a re-usable API that shipped in 2.1 as a first class BCL API" ...

Comment: Now I finally found the concrete location: it's in System.Net.Sockets.dll in class named System.Net.SocketTaskExtensions (which is only available for .net core 2.1): https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.receiveasync?view=netcore-2.1#System_Net_Sockets_SocketTaskExtensions_ReceiveAsync_System_Net_Sockets_Socket_System_Memory_System_Byte__System_Net_Sockets_SocketFlags_System_Threading_CancellationToken_